# How can I get geolocation with geocoder and save data using promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm building up a `PUT` function which updates a user profile. By doing it I want to convert the address in geolocation coordinates, in order to enable a geolocation search.

I'm trying to do this asynchronously, but I have some trouble in making it work.

Here my function:

```
//PUT: Update profile
app.put('/api/userData', isLoggedInAjax, function(req, res){

    var user = req.user;

    user.profile.username           = req.body.username;
    user.profile.instrument         = req.body.instrument;
    user.profile.location.country   = req.body.country;
    user.profile.location.city      = req.body.city;
    user.profile.location.zip       = req.body.zip;
    user.geolocation                = [];

    var address = req.body.zip +' '+req.body.city +' '+req.body.country;

    nodeGeocoder.geocode(address)
    .then(function(result){
        user.geolocation[0] = result[0].longitude;
        user.geolocation[1] = result[0].latitude;
        return user;

    });


    user.save(function(err){
            if (err) res.send(err);
            res.json({ message: 'profile udated'});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the old "how do I do asynchronous programming in JavaScript" question. You have to invoke the save function from the callback:

```
//PUT: Update profile
app.put('/api/userData', isLoggedInAjax, function(req, res){

    var user = req.user;

    user.profile.username           = req.body.username;
    user.profile.instrument         = req.body.instrument;
    user.profile.location.country   = req.body.country;
    user.profile.location.city      = req.body.city;
    user.profile.location.zip       = req.body.zip;
    user.geolocation                = [];

    var address = req.body.zip +' '+req.body.city +' '+req.body.country;

    nodeGeocoder.geocode(address)
    .then(function(result){
        user.geolocation[0] = result[0].longitude;
        user.geolocation[1] = result[0].latitude;

        user.save(function(err){
            if (err) res.send(err);
            res.json({ message: 'profile udated'});
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try tracing through the code and callbacks carefully using console.logs or a debugger like the built-in (https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) or Webstorm.  You will need to trace the execution carefully because the way callbacks and promises work is confusing until you really get used to it.

Then once you understand the order of the execution for your code, you can solve your problem using another `.then` in your promise chain or by converting this to use the `async/await` syntax and compiling with babel.

Using `async/await` is the most straightforward and maintainable/understandable way, but you might really have to learn callbacks and promises pretty well in order to take advantage of it.